# Add custom apex:inputFile icon/image

Tags: css

I'm using an inputFile button to upload some files...

The button renders on my page as a grey 'Choose File To Upload' button. Can I add my own custom icon/image in place of the button?

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is more related to CSS. You can achieve this by CSS.

Just provide you inputFile tag a class like:

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" styleclass="fileType"/>
```

And apply the CSS from this link:

```
html {
  margin: 30px;
}
.fileType {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: 0;
}
.fileType:hover:after {
    background: #FF1111;
}
.fileType:after {
    transition: 200ms all ease;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: #000000;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVpp3.jpg');
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    content: 'Upload Something';
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Or you can play with your own CSS too and you can provide your own image url for `background` property of CSS.

Comment: Excellent! Cheers regal. Cool styles too!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old, maybe you will find the following example useful ([live snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/x6mfob31/1/)).

VF / HTML part:

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file"/>
    Custom Upload
</label>
```

OR

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

CSS part:

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    color: #333;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    border-bottom-color: #7f7f7f;
    background: #e8e8e9 url(https://i.imgur.com/RdRFrhh.png) repeat-x right top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .9em;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Result:

[image]

I highly recommending checking this question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button